# PCI compliance with multiple AWS VPCs

Tags: aws, pci-scope

If I have VPC which is in-scope (the "PCI VPC") and another which is not (the "NON-PCI VPC"), would peering them bring the non-pci vpc in-scope? Is there a way to avoid this?

I have an aurora RDS inside the PCI VPC. It does not actually contain sensitive information, but is used by services which do. What is the best way to share this non-pci data with the non-pci VPC without inadvertently bringing that VPC into scope?

Options:

1. Peer the VPCs (protected with SGs based on CIDR)
2. Replicate the DB in the other VPC (it only needs read).
3. Access the RDS via external endpoint
4. ...?

I don't think any of these options are quite right, but I'm hoping you will correct me or suggest a better option.

Answer (score 2):

This is from the [PCI-DSS guideline](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/Guidance-PCI-DSS-Scoping-and-Segmentation_v1.pdf):

> In order for a system to be considered out of scope, controls must be
>   in place to provide reasonable assurance that the out-of-scope system
>   cannot be used to compromise an in-scope system component, as . the
>   in-scope system could then be used to gain access to the CDE or impact
>   security of the CDE. Examples of controls that could be applied to
>   prevent out-of-scope systems from compromising a connected-to
>   orsecurity-impacting system include:
>
> - Host-based firewall and/or intrusion detection and prevention system    (IDS/IPS) on in-scope systems that block connection attempts
>     from    out-of-scope systems.
> - Physical access controls that allow only designated users to access    in-scope systems.
> - Logical access controls that permit only designated users to login to    in-scope systems.
> - Multi-factor authentication on in-scope systems.
> - Restricting administrative access privileges to designated users and    systems/networks.
> - Actively monitoring for suspicious network or system behavior that    could indicate an out-of-scope system attempting to gain access to an 
>     in-scope system component or the CDE.

So in short having peering isn't an issue as long as you have strong control to segregate access to sensitive systems. If your RDS does not contain sensitive information but your PCI systems still require to read from the RDS, you can put rules in place that your PCI scoped systems can pull information from the RDS but the RDS itself cannot push information. If your RDS is not a CDE, then I suggest you move it out. Ideally you have three tiers of network, where one is your CDE, one is a middle ground for information exchange and one is your more "general" environment. This will make it easier for you to segregate and apply monitoring as well.